# Why gerrit can't use H2 database command g s q l?

Tags: gerrit

I want to use gerrit's gsql,but it can't be found.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Gerrit 3.x.y which doesn't use a relational database anymore. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749296/gerritversion3-4-1-execute-ssh-p-29418-usernamexx-xx-xx-xx-gerrit-gsql).