# gerrit(version:3.4.1), execute (ssh -p 29418 username@xx.xx.xx.xx gerrit gsql), return(fatal: gerrit: gsql: not found)

Tags: h2, gerrit

Our gerrit version is 3.4.1, when i execute `ssh -p 29418 username@xx.xx.xx.xx gerrit gsql`, it return `fatal: gerrit: gsql: not found`.

And when i execute `ssh -p 29418 usename@xx.xx.xx.xx gerrit --help`, there is no `gsql` cmd in the returned gerrit instructions list.

How can i operate gerrit database?

Answer (score 1):

Gerrit 3.0 onwards has removed the use of an external database in favor of the git based noteDb and gsql has been removed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.x, Gerrit switched the internal database to [NotesDB](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/note-db.html).

You can directly use `git` to access the notes (which represent the dabase content). For example, to query a change, you could

```
$ git init
$ git fetch https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit refs/changes/40/329240/meta
$ git log -p FETCH_HEAD
```

(Example adopted from the [NotesDb](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/note-db.html) backend documentation page, where you can find more information as well.)

Comment: thanks so much for your help.  Could you mind me asking how do i ``use git to access the notes``? Is there some specific cmd？

Comment: It's just plain git -- I added an example. Feel free to accept / vote my answer if it's useful : )